# Calendar layout using nested flexbox divs - containers not stacking

Tags: html, css, calendar, flexbox

I am trying to create a calendar header using flexbox for the layout of the years, months, days though I am having trouble achieving the expected result.

What am I doing wrong? Is it how I have structured the HTML or am I missing something in the CSS?

Expected result is something similar to this:

[image]

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
.year,
.month,
.day {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  height: 20px;
}
.year {
  background-color: red;
}
.month {
  background-color: blue;
}
.day {
  background-color: green;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="year flex">2015
    <div class="month flex">Jan
      <div class="day">01</div>
      <div class="day">02</div>
      <div class="day">03</div>
      <div class="day">04</div>
      <div class="day">05</div>
      <div class="day">06</div>
      <div class="day">07</div>
      <div class="day">08</div>
    </div>
    <div class="month flex">Feb
      <div class="day">01</div>
      <div class="day">02</div>
      <div class="day">03</div>
      <div class="day">04</div>
      <div class="day">05</div>
      <div class="day">06</div>
      <div class="day">07</div>
      <div class="day">08</div>
    </div>
    <div class="month flex">Mar
      <div class="day">01</div>
      <div class="day">02</div>
      <div class="day">03</div>
      <div class="day">04</div>
      <div class="day">05</div>
      <div class="day">06</div>
      <div class="day">07</div>
      <div class="day">08</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="year flex">2016
    <div class="month flex">Jan
      <div class="day">01</div>
      <div class="day">02</div>
      <div class="day">03</div>
      <div class="day">04</div>
      <div class="day">05</div>
      <div class="day">06</div>
      <div class="day">07</div>
      <div class="day">08</div>
    </div>
    <div class="month flex">Feb
      <div class="day">01</div>
      <div class="day">02</div>
      <div class="day">03</div>
      <div class="day">04</div>
      <div class="day">05</div>
      <div class="day">06</div>
      <div class="day">07</div>
      <div class="day">08</div>
    </div>
    <div class="month flex">Mar
      <div class="day">01</div>
      <div class="day">02</div>
      <div class="day">03</div>
      <div class="day">04</div>
      <div class="day">05</div>
      <div class="day">06</div>
      <div class="day">07</div>
      <div class="day">08</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed the .flex class replaced with .eqWrap (personal preference since I added eqHW for equal height and width), one of your problems was caused by using flex-flow: row nowrap;. Another problem I saw was you didn't set the flex-boxes to be equal width and height. Also I got rid of the width on the day class. The HTML code issues I saw were you didn't put all the months together, and then the days together and you combined everything in one flex box div, which also causes everything to appear on one line.

```
div {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}


.eqWrap {
 display: flex;
}

.year{
 background: red;
}
.month {
 background: blue;
}
.day {
 background: green;
}

.month, .day, .year {
 border: 1px solid gray;
 text-align:center;
 
}
.equalHW {
 height:20px;
 flex: 1;
}
 <div class="equalHW year">2015</div>
 <div class="eqWrap">
    <div class="equalHW month">Jan</div>
    <div class="equalHW month">Feb</div>
    <div class="equalHW month">Mar</div>
 </div>
  <div class="eqWrap">
    <div class="equalHW day">1</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">2</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">3</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">4</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">5</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">6</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">7</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">8</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">1</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">2</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">3</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">4</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">5</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">6</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">7</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">8</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">1</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">2</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">3</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">4</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">5</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">6</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">7</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">8</div>
 </div>
 
  <div class="equalHW year">2016</div>
 <div class="eqWrap">
    <div class="equalHW month">Jan</div>
    <div class="equalHW month">Feb</div>
    <div class="equalHW month">Mar</div>
 </div>
  <div class="eqWrap">
    <div class="equalHW day">1</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">2</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">3</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">4</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">5</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">6</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">7</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">8</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">1</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">2</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">3</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">4</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">5</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">6</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">7</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">8</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">1</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">2</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">3</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">4</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">5</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">6</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">7</div>
    <div class="equalHW day">8</div>
 </div>
```